# Cast exception to entity Object using EntityManager and EntityManagerFactory

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, persistence

I'm not able use @PersistenceContext with a new bean I created, resulting always on the entity manager variable being null.

So I searched the net for a solution for this problem, with no results.
Instead I tried using EntityManagerFactory which returns data perfectly but then I cannot transfer it to a new variable of the same entity type.

What I notice is that the contents of l.get(0) has, besides the normal Products object  fields, some extra ones appear like _persistence_listener, _persistence_primaryKey, etc...and then the cast is not successful.

How can I cast the result to Products objects again without throwing the exception "com.jogogestao.entity.Product cannot be cast to com.jogogestao.entity.Product"?

Tkx!

The Code:

```
public Product getProduct (int ProductId){
        private EntityManager em;
    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JogoGestao-ejbPU"); 
        Product p = null;

        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        Query querysql = em.createQuery("select p from Product p where p.idProduct=" + ProductId);
        List<Product> l = querysql.getResultList();
        p=l.get(0); //The error occurs here
}
```

Product.java:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.jogogestao.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

/**
 *
 * @author BirdOfPrey
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByIdProduct", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.idProduct = :idProduct"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductName", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productName = :productName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductBuyPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productBuyPrice = :productBuyPrice"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductSellPrice", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productSellPrice = :productSellPrice"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductStoreStockQtd", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productStoreStockQtd = :productStoreStockQtd"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductShelfSpace", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productShelfSpace = :productShelfSpace"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductSubCategoryId", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productSubCategoryId = :productSubCategoryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductStoreRefillTime", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productStoreRefillTime = :productStoreRefillTime"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductStoreCentralQtd", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productStoreCentralQtd = :productStoreCentralQtd"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductStoreWarehouseQtd", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productStoreWarehouseQtd = :productStoreWarehouseQtd"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductRange", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productRange = :productRange"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductWarehouseResponseTime", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productWarehouseResponseTime = :productWarehouseResponseTime"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Product.findByProductCentralResponseTime", query = "SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.productCentralResponseTime = :productCentralResponseTime")})
public class Product implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "idProduct")
    private Integer idProduct;
    @Size(max = 5000)
    @Column(name = "ProductName")
    private String productName;
    // @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
    @Column(name = "ProductBuyPrice")
    private BigDecimal productBuyPrice;
    @Column(name = "ProductSellPrice")
    private BigDecimal productSellPrice;
    @Column(name = "ProductStoreStockQtd")
    private Integer productStoreStockQtd;
    @Column(name = "ProductShelfSpace")
    private Integer productShelfSpace;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "ProductSubCategoryId")
    private String productSubCategoryId;
    @Column(name = "ProductStoreRefillTime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date productStoreRefillTime;
    @Column(name = "ProductStoreCentralQtd")
    private Integer productStoreCentralQtd;
    @Column(name = "ProductStoreWarehouseQtd")
    private Integer productStoreWarehouseQtd;
    @Column(name = "ProductRange")
    private Integer productRange;
    @Column(name = "ProductWarehouseResponseTime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date productWarehouseResponseTime;
    @Column(name = "ProductCentralResponseTime")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
    private Date productCentralResponseTime;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ProductCategoryId", referencedColumnName = "idProductCategory")
    @ManyToOne
    private Productcategory productCategoryId;

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(Integer idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    public Integer getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(Integer idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getProductBuyPrice() {
        return productBuyPrice;
    }

    public void setProductBuyPrice(BigDecimal productBuyPrice) {
        this.productBuyPrice = productBuyPrice;
    }

    public BigDecimal getProductSellPrice() {
        return productSellPrice;
    }

    public void setProductSellPrice(BigDecimal productSellPrice) {
        this.productSellPrice = productSellPrice;
    }

    public Integer getProductStoreStockQtd() {
        return productStoreStockQtd;
    }

    public void setProductStoreStockQtd(Integer productStoreStockQtd) {
        this.productStoreStockQtd = productStoreStockQtd;
    }

    public Integer getProductShelfSpace() {
        return productShelfSpace;
    }

    public void setProductShelfSpace(Integer productShelfSpace) {
        this.productShelfSpace = productShelfSpace;
    }

    public String getProductSubCategoryId() {
        return productSubCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductSubCategoryId(String productSubCategoryId) {
        this.productSubCategoryId = productSubCategoryId;
    }

    public Date getProductStoreRefillTime() {
        return productStoreRefillTime;
    }

    public void setProductStoreRefillTime(Date productStoreRefillTime) {
        this.productStoreRefillTime = productStoreRefillTime;
    }

    public Integer getProductStoreCentralQtd() {
        return productStoreCentralQtd;
    }

    public void setProductStoreCentralQtd(Integer productStoreCentralQtd) {
        this.productStoreCentralQtd = productStoreCentralQtd;
    }

    public Integer getProductStoreWarehouseQtd() {
        return productStoreWarehouseQtd;
    }

    public void setProductStoreWarehouseQtd(Integer productStoreWarehouseQtd) {
        this.productStoreWarehouseQtd = productStoreWarehouseQtd;
    }

    public Integer getProductRange() {
        return productRange;
    }

    public void setProductRange(Integer productRange) {
        this.productRange = productRange;
    }

    public Date getProductWarehouseResponseTime() {
        return productWarehouseResponseTime;
    }

    public void setProductWarehouseResponseTime(Date productWarehouseResponseTime) {
        this.productWarehouseResponseTime = productWarehouseResponseTime;
    }

    public Date getProductCentralResponseTime() {
        return productCentralResponseTime;
    }

    public void setProductCentralResponseTime(Date productCentralResponseTime) {
        this.productCentralResponseTime = productCentralResponseTime;
    }

    public Productcategory getProductCategoryId() {
        return productCategoryId;
    }

    public void setProductCategoryId(Productcategory productCategoryId) {
        this.productCategoryId = productCategoryId;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (idProduct != null ? idProduct.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Product)) {
            return false;
        }
        Product other = (Product) object;
        if ((this.idProduct == null && other.idProduct != null) || (this.idProduct != null && !this.idProduct.equals(other.idProduct))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.jogogestao.entity.Product[ idProduct=" + idProduct + " ]";
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.jogogestao.entity.Product cannot be cast to com.jogogestao.entity.Product
    at com.jogogestao.ejb.DataAccess.getProduct(DataAccess.java:57)
    at com.jogogestao.ejb.JogoGestaoSession.addProduct(JogoGestaoSession.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor199.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 47 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, you have classloading problems. `List<Product> l = querysql.getResultList();` here Product was loading with a different class loader than your code. I think the problem is here `private static EntityManagerFactory emf = javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JogoGestao-ejbPU");`

1. Try to fetch EntityManagerFactory from your code (not in static initilization) and see if the problem is resolved.
2. Check how do you define use of Persistance and which classloader is in use theire. I think the problem is that wrong classloader is used in order to load `javax.persistence.*` classes.

Answer (score 0):

If the method `getProduct` is in a `servlet`, `ManagedBean` or `EJB`, let the container manage the lifecycle of your PersistenceContext by injection:

```
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;
```

If the Persistence Unit is correctly defined in your `persistence.xml` and in the container, this is more than enough.

In order to understand the usage of Enterprise Beans, read carefully the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnblr.html)

Comment: Something very strange is happening with that project on the glassfish server, so I rebuilt the entire project with a new name and the same exact code now works ok...go figure